# Saving settings in user.config

Tags: c#

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587110/basic-user-input-string-validation) came up today on StackOverflow. I find it more unfortunate than (as some others said) idiotic. And it recalled an old function I have which I just remembered.

I have a user.config file which has some settings which can be updated through user action. My rationale was "if the setting is changed, it should be saved." So I made a static class to cover for those settings so as not to handle the operations each time. And I came up with this:

```
public static class UserSettings
{
    public static string ProcessPath
    {
        get { return _processPath; }
        set 
        { 
            _processPath = Settings.Default.ProcessPath = value;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
    //Other functions and properties
}
```

Yes, I know, it reeks. I feel shame. I want to make this right. I'm thinking this:

- the class is static, it should at least be a singleton;
- the property should itself not be static;
- there's no point in saving the settings *every time*, just on closing the app, and that would basically <strike>be safe in a destructor for the class</strike> be best suited for a dedicated function called SaveSettings. Any other object can call it when they see fit, no surprise effects. (further evidence of the need for a singleton).

Are these *good intentions* in the right direction?

Comment: Oh my, that question you linked to just killed a part of my soul.  Ouch.  Your example however, I don't really have a problem with.

Comment: You are welcome to see my post then. You are almost right, there is no troubles using application/user scope with settings along with singletone implementation in .NET. Just use singleton serialization helper and serializatpion class, inherited from ISerializable interface, and make use of the Default static property to access your serialized properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think making it a singleton would be a mistake (singleton usually is). At best it would be extra work with zero benefit. At worst, it's a handicap, such as when/if you decide to support two top-level windows with independent settings for each.

Second, I think I'd add a Boolean named `dirty` (or something similar). When you set the value, dirty is set to true. When you save the value, you check if dirty is true, and only write out the value if it is (then you set dirty to false).

Personally, I'd probably change it from a static class named `ProcessPath` to a normal class named (something like) `config_string`, with an instance for ProcessPath, and a the possibility for other instances holding other strings. To do that, you'd pass `Settings.Default.ProcessPath` as a parameter when you construct the object.

Comment: Why do you say singletons usually are mistakes?

Comment: @MPelletier: If you Google for something like `singleton antipattern`, you should get [some](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337) [pretty](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-join-new-project.html) [decent](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/21/where-have-all-the-singletons-gone/) [ideas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).

Comment: A dirty for every value? What if a class contains 100 values?

Comment: @0A0D: Right now it contains *one* value. If it contains 100 values, it will depend. If each can be/is reasonably written out separately, then probably yes. If they're all going to be written together, then a single Boolean suffices for all of them. Keep in mind that 100 bits is only 12.5 bytes. Even if you round up to 13 or even 16 (next power of 2), and it's still pretty minimal. You don't have to save many writes to disk to justify 16 bytes of storage.

Comment: @0A0D @Jerry Actually, since this is basically a cover class for user.config settings, `Settings.Default.Save();` saves all values, so a single `dirty` variable would suffice.

Comment: @MPelletier : I've got an idea, please, see my post then.

Comment: If you use a constructor initialization, you will likely not be very happy to write as a paremeters 100 values, that is why IoC, DI is on the play. It is much simplier to have attributed 100 properties rathen than pass it to the constructor. It is based on a practice.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your idea. You have to use both patterns: singleton pattern, and load/save pattern.

You can use `UserSettings` class implementation, with load/save functionality, inherited from the `ApplicationSettingsBase` class.

Example of using `UserSettings` singleton class in Windows Forms Application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Location = UserSettings.Default.FormLocation;
        this.Size = UserSettings.Default.FormSize;
        this.textBox1.Text = UserSettings.Default.ProcessPath;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        UserSettings.Default.FormLocation = this.Location;
        UserSettings.Default.FormSize = this.Size;
        UserSettings.Default.ProcessPath = this.textBox1.Text;
        UserSettings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Sources:

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
public sealed class UserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase, INotifyPropertyChanged, ISerializable
{
    private static UserSettings _defaultInstance = new UserSettings();

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.SetType(typeof(SingletonSerializationHelper));
    }

    private UserSettings() { }

    public static UserSettings Default { get { return _defaultInstance; } }

    private const string FormLocationProperty = "FormLocation";
    private const string FormSizeProperty = "FormSize";
    private const string ProcessPathProperty = "ProcessPath";

    // public properties
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue("0, 0")]
    public Point FormLocation
    {
        get { return (Point)(this[FormLocationProperty]); }
        set { this[FormLocationProperty] = value; }
    }

    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue("300, 300")]
    public Size FormSize
    {
        get { return (Size)this[FormSizeProperty]; }
        set { this[FormSizeProperty] = value; }
    }

    [UserScopedSetting]
    [DefaultSettingValue("")]
    public string ProcessPath
    {
        get { return (string)this[ProcessPathProperty]; }
        set { this[ProcessPathProperty] = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
internal sealed class SingletonSerializationHelper : IObjectReference
{
    public object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
    {
        return UserSettings.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you did with the singleton pattern. Impressive, I had always just seen GetInstance(), never an actual named oject. I guess it tells us the original Properties.Settings.Default is itself a singleton... Your class would serialize (and deserialize) as user.config? What would be the advantage here?

Comment: @MPelletier: There is no real advantage of using this class except it is a singleton and is an ancestor of the `ApplicationSettingsBase` class, and can be used anywere `ApplicationSettingsBase` is used. So it solves the problem of multiple instancies of applications settings classes, in my opinion. Persistent storage, accessible anywere, which also has default values set, etc.

Comment: I think I see... A lot of that stuff I don't need in the current project. Way too much overhead. But in the right place, it would be very useful. I'm just not sure where the right place would be at the moment. That is by no means a way of saying I don't like your solution. I do like it. I'm just not sure I understand all of it :S

Comment: @PMelletier: It's OK. This is a community. I got another solutions, which you can find in my careers profile, f.e. you can use custom XML serialization to serialize anything you want at http://xmlserialization.codeplex.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cheats I use -

To prevent having to type "Settings.Default":

```
using Res = MyApp.Properties.Resources;
using Set = MyApp.Properties.Settings;

/// in class
private static Set def{
  get{
    return Set.Default;
  }
}
// usage
def.Data="blah"
```

And then take a look at

```
public event SettingChangingEventHandler SettingChanging
```

of ApplicationSettingsBase